# Раздельное написание частицы НЕ с причастиями

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно, причастия

> Так и не заданный вопрос.

Правильно ли раздельное написание и почему?

Comment: А полное предложение? Например: *Ответа требует как заданный, так и незаданный вопрос.*

Comment: Такой вопрос задан на другом сайте (предложение такого формата...). Ответили, что нужно слитное написание. А я думаю, что в данном случае "так и" выступает в качестве пояснительного слова (никто не задал вопрос).

Comment: Ответ зависит от контекста.

Comment: Понимаю. В таком контексте трудно сказать  точно?

Comment: А если такое предложение: "Повис в воздухе так и не заданный вопрос"?

Comment: Раздельно пишется не с причастиями, имеющими при себе зависимые слова.

Comment: Я это знаю. Вопрос по данному случаю.

Comment: Это данный случай. Повис в воздухе так и не заданный вопрос. *Так* — слово, зависимое от  *заданный*.

Comment: Спасибо! Я так и думала.

Answer (score 2):

**Повис в воздухе так и не заданный вопрос.**

ТАК И — частица. Это усиленное отрицание, раздельное написание НЕ.

**Толковый словарь Ефремовой**

II част. разг. 1. Употребляется при подчеркивании энергичного, интенсивного непроизвольно совершающегося действия. 2. Употребляется при подчеркивании значения итога, результата предшествующего действия. **3. Употребляется для усиления эмоционально окрашенного несогласия или отрицания.**

Источник: https://gufo.me/dict/efremova/%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D0%B8

Примеры:

Бедная моя Катя, **так и не найденная**, где-нибудь на вокзале с выбитыми окнами, среди спящих, бредящих и мертвых, позовет в последний раз: «Вадим, Вадим…» [А. Н. Толстой. Хождение по мукам/ Книга третья. Хмурое утро (1941)]

Некоторая любопытнейшая, хотя **так и не написанная** часть повести была обдумана именно здесь, под меланхолическое бульканье Минусовой флейты. [Л. М. Леонов. Вор. Части 1-2 (1927)]

Рядом ...стояло «Преображение» ― последняя картина, начатая им ещё в 1517 году и **так и не законченная**. [С. А. Еремеева. Лекции по истории искусства (1999)]

Answer (score 1):

***Повис в воздухе так и не заданный вопрос.***

Не согласен с М_Г: в этом предложении "так" — не зависимое от причастия "заданный" слово, а часть частицы "так и", обычно употребляемой с отрицанием "не" для подчёркивания значения итога, результата предшествующего действия.

При синтаксическом разборе предложения эту частицу стоит считать частью определения:

*Вопрос* какой? — *так и не заданный*.

О частице "так и"… *"Большой универсальный словарь русского языка"* под ред. Морковкина (М., 2016):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так или иначе, пишем раздельно. В этом мы согласны. О частице "так и" с причастиями, увы, не нашел, но нашел, что "вовсе не",  "отнюдь не" пишется раздельно.

Comment: М_Г, Вы не нашли "так и" в значении частицы, или же не нашли "так и" в значении частицы в сочетании именно с причастиями? Т. е. в сочетании с глаголами Вы "так и" признаете за частицу, а в сочетании с причастиями — нет?

Comment: Поставим вопрос так: чувствую,  что писать надо раздельно, но не нашел указания на то, что частица это позволяет (У Лопатина, например, про зависимые слова да про усиление отрицания, типа отнюдь не успокоенный, нимало не смущённая, нисколько не обрадованный, никем не замеченный, никогда не унывающий, никем не любимый).

Comment: Но ведь это усилительная частица? Усиливает она отрицание, а при явном отрицании пишется раздельно.

Answer (score 0):

> Повис в воздухе так и не заданный вопрос.

Раздельно пишется не с причастиями, имеющими при себе зависимые слова. *Так* — слово, зависимое от причастия *заданный*.

*Ответа требует как заданный, так и незаданный вопрос.*

В этом предложении у причастия нет зависимых слов, поэтому *не* пишется слитно.

Дополнение. Должен признать правоту моих критиков. Раздельное написание частицы *не* следует объяснять по-другому (см. ответы slava1947, Sharon, замечания Людмилы). Оставляю свой ответ, чтобы понятней был ход развития дискуссии.

Comment: Разве возможно поставить вопрос: Не заданный (как?)- так? Это не зависимое слово, это усилительная частица "да и".

Comment: Огромное спасибо всем, кто принял участие в дискуссии по поводу раздельного (или слитного) написания причастия! Я убедилась еще раз в своей правоте.